Potential reason why deployment would change the dimentions of the elements in next app?
Maybe someone knows why when deploying the website (on vercel) the dimensions of the elements change slightly.
But if you use devtools and set the same dimensions as the used device - it displays everything how it was on the local env.
What could be the potential reasons?
I am adjusting the code and pushing it to the repo, but now there are 2 different versions on local and deployed (in terms of visual), but they run on the same code.

Maybe you're zoomed in?

gosh, yes :D
I am a mokey, I had an 80% oom on localhost. Thank you!

I've done it myself :)
